# Как разбить Main на отдельные структуры?

Tags: java

У меня сортировка двусвязного списка. Нужно разбить `Main` и `public static List sort` на отдельные структуры, а не использовать в сущ. классе `Main.java`.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(2);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(9);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(6);
        System.out.println("Inpt List: " + list);
        List list2 = sort(list);
        System.out.println("Sort List: " + list2);
    }
    public static List<Integer> sort(List<Integer> list) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int element : list) {
            if (element < min)
                min = element;
            if (element > max)
                max = element;
        }
        int[] buckets = new int[max - min + 1];
        for (int element : list)
            buckets[element - min]++;
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
            for (int j = buckets[i]; j > 0; j--)
                list.set(arrayIndex++, i + min);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит не переиспользовать существующие классы? Мы не понимаем в чём ИМЕННО у вас возникла трудность. Поэтому мы не можем дать вам верный ответ.

Comment: Так а что вам нужно вынести? Метод sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(2);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(9);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(6);

        System.out.println("Inpt List: " + list);

        List list2 = MySort.list(list);

        System.out.println("Sort List: " + list2);

    }
}

public class MySort {
    public static List<Integer> list(List<Integer> list) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int element : list) {
            if (element < min)
                min = element;
            if (element > max)
                max = element;
        }
        int[] buckets = new int[max - min + 1];
        for (int element : list)
            buckets[element - min]++;
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
            for (int j = buckets[i]; j > 0; j--)
                list.set(arrayIndex++, i + min);

        return list;
    }
}
```